# Can a Google calendar go on a map?

Tags: google-maps, google, google-maps-api, georss

Can a Google calendar go on a Google map?

Is there a GeoRSS that can be consumed?

Comment: http://chadnorwood.com/gcm/ XML/KML can be consumed